# How can you create an "aligned" array of bytes and read from it?

Tags: swift, pointers, memory

I want to be able to use the [UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load(fromByteOffset:as:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawbufferpointer/2632297-load) method to read a number of bytes from a [UInt8] array and their corresponding type as an `UnsignedInteger`, `FixedWidthInteger` at each read.

In both approaches that follow, a "Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer" exception is raised, since `load` [expects the underlying data to be aligned in memory](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10273).

I have tried using a `ContiguousArray`

```
    var words: ContiguousArray<UInt8> = [0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xec, 0xfa, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x88, 0x47, 0xa3, 0xd6, 0x6b, 0xd6, 0x01, 0x4c, 0xff, 0x08]
    
    var offset = 0
    let byte = words.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt8.self) }
    offset += MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
    let bytes = words.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt16.self) }

    XCTAssertEqual(byte, UInt8(littleEndian: 0x01))
    XCTAssertEqual(bytes, UInt16(littleEndian: 0x0003))
```

Allocating and initialising a [UnsafeMutablePointer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer)

```
    var words: [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xec, 0xfa, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x88, 0x47, 0xa3, 0xd6, 0x6b, 0xd6, 0x01, 0x4c, 0xff, 0x08]
    
    let uint8Pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: words.count)
    uint8Pointer.initialize(from: &words, count: words.count)
    
    let rawPointer = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(uint8Pointer)
    
    var offset = 0
    let byte = UInt8(bigEndian: rawPointer.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt8.self))
    offset += MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
    let bytes = UInt16(bigEndian: rawPointer.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt16.self))

    rawPointer.deallocate()

    uint8Pointer.deinitialize(count: words.count)
    uint8Pointer.deallocate()

    XCTAssertEqual(byte, UInt8(littleEndian: 0x01))
    XCTAssertEqual(bytes, UInt16(littleEndian: 0x0003))
```

Can you please point out where my misunderstanding lies in each and provide a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

1. `UnsafeMutablePointer` makes no alignment guarantees. One could use POSIX functions (like `posix_memalign`) instead, but that does not really help if ...
2. The values are at arbitrarily byte offsets in the byte array. As an example, if `a: UInt16`, `b: UInt8`, `c: UInt32` are packed (in this order)

   ```
   aa aa bb cc cc cc cc
   ```

   then there is no way to align this buffer such that all integer values   are properly aligned.
3. Unfortunately, there are no methods yet to load or initialize a value from unaligned data. (This has been suggested ([1](https://forums.swift.org/t/built-in-unaligned-loads/19664), [2](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10273)) but not yet implemented). It does not matter if you use `Array`, `ContiguousArray`, or `Data` as the byte source.

The safest way is still to load the bytes and use bit shifting to combine them to the values:

```
let byteArray: Array<UInt8> = [0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0a]
var offset = 0
let ui8 = byteArray[offset]
print(ui8) // 1
offset += MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
let ui16 = UInt16(byteArray[offset]) << 8 + UInt16(byteArray[offset + 1])
print(ui16) // 3
```

An alternative is to *copy* the bytes (and do the byte-order conversion):

```
let byteArray: Array<UInt8> = [0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0a]
var offset = 0
var ui8 = UInt8(0)
_ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &ui8, { byteArray.copyBytes(to: $0, from: offset...) } )
print(ui8) // 1
offset += MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
var ui16 = UInt16(0)
_ = withUnsafeMutableBytes(of: &ui16, { byteArray.copyBytes(to: $0, from: offset...) } )
print(UInt16(bigEndian: ui16)) // 3
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer. Are you suggesting there is no way to create a raw byte buffer, with an aligned memory so that it can be read by a pointer?

Comment: Not with [`UnsafeMutablePointer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer): *“UnsafeMutablePointer provides no automated memory management or alignment guarantees.”*. There are POSIX functions (like `posix_memalign`) which are available in Swift. But that does not help if the values are at an arbitrary position in the buffer (like the UInt16 at offset 1 in your example).

Comment: Can you please post that as an answer so that I can accept? Given that there is no way to satisfy the precondition for `UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load(fromByteOffset:as:)`, when using an offset, is there a use case at all when using Swift?

Comment: @qnoid: I have added it to the answer. And yes, the `load(fromByteOffset:as:)` method is often useless because you don't know how the storage is aligned.

Answer (score 1):

One way to guarantee an “aligned” array of bytes is by using the same `UnsignedInteger`, `FixedWidthInteger` type.  Since the array is homogenous, alignment is guaranteed by the size of each type.

e.g. a [UInt8] array that holds byte types

```
        var array: [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x00, 0x03]

        var offset = 0
        let byte = array.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt8.self) }

        offset += MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
        let bytee = array.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt8.self) }

        offset += MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
        let byteee = array.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt8.self) }

        XCTAssertEqual(byte, 0x01)
        XCTAssertEqual(bytee, 0x00)
        XCTAssertEqual(byteee, 0x03)
```

e.g. a [UInt8] array that holds 2 byte types

```
        var array: [UInt8] = [0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x01]

        var offset = 0
        let bytes = UInt16(bigEndian: array.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt16.self) })

        offset += MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
        let bytess = UInt16(bigEndian: array.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt16.self) })

        offset += MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size
        let bytesss = UInt16(bigEndian: array.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(fromByteOffset: offset, as: UInt16.self) })

        XCTAssertEqual(bytes, 0x0100)
        XCTAssertEqual(bytess, 0x030a)
        XCTAssertEqual(bytesss, 0x0001)
```

The misunderstanding lies in that, it is not possible to have an "aligned" array of bytes when types stored in the array can't be aligned given their mismatched size.

The size of UInt8 being 1 byte and the size of UInt16 being 2 bytes in this case creating an unaligned array that is not supported by  `UnsafeRawBufferPointer.load(fromByteOffset:as:)`.